# String to class mvc c# for use Job in Quartz

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I want to make 1 job and 1 schedule using quartz, but every job is run based table in the database

```
foreach (var i in query) { 
scheduler.ScheduleJob(JobBuilder.Create<i.classname>().Build(), TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                        .WithIntervalInSeconds(40)
                        .RepeatForever()
                      )
                    .Build());
}
```

i.classname is a string, how to make a class ?

Comment: Hi Rahmad, welcome to stackoverflow.  I voted to close your question as a duplicate because I think the other one covers your question.  If that doesn't help, just [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged with asp.net mvc or model-view-controller.  You might be using those, but they bear no relevance to your question.  Why wasn't this tagged with Quartz?

Comment: You probably want the 2nd duplicate link. Get the `Type` instance and pass that in to the `ScheduleJob` method overload that takes a `Type` as parameter. You can only use the overload that that uses a Generic type argument if you know the type at compile time, which you do not.

Comment: type class not found, where i get example it ?